# What could cause one side of the TCP connection in FIN_WAIT2 state and the other side is fully closed (i.e. not in CLOSE_WAIT state)?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, tcp

I recently encountered an TCP related issue and hope someone could shed some light on it.

I have an application1 in container1/pod1 that is connected to a server `(client_ip:12345 <-> server_ip:443).` After running for a while, the server decided to close this connection, so it sent FIN to the client and the client sends ACK back to the server (saw these two packets in the pcap). This sould leave the client in **CLOSE_WAIT** and the server in **FIN_WAIT2**.

In this situation, the client should call close() and send FIN back to the server. But I've found that the application lack close() in its code, so in theory, the client should be stuck in **CLOSE_WAIT** and the server will be in **FIN_WAIT2** until **FIN_WAIT2** timeout. The port 12345 on the client side shouldn't be reused by any other new connections.

However, it seems somehow the client_ip:12345 <-> server_ip:443 socket state on the client side was no longer in **CLOSE_WAIT** state (become fully closed and available), so when another application2 in container2 was up, it randomly pick the same port 12345 (the kernel assign the ephemeral source port from the range) to connect to the server's port 443. Because the server side were still in **FIN_WAIT2**, so the connection couldn't be established, and thus the service got interrupted until **FIN_WAIT2** state timeout (300 secs).

I understand I should fix the application code by adding close(). However, I'm curious about what could make the CLOSE_WAIT state disappear/reset on the client side and let another application be able to pick the same 12345 port to connect to the server?

I found a F5 Bug mentioned a similar situation: `"Client side connection has been fully closed. This may occur if a client SSL profile is in use and an 'Encrypted Alert' has been received."`

> https://cdn.f5.com/product/bugtracker/ID812693.html

I'm wondering if there are any other possibilities that could cause **FIN_WAIT2** on one side and fully closed on the other side (not in **CLOSE_WAIT**)?

For example, the process using this socket was killed? But AFAIK, after killing that process, the socket file descriptor should be closed and a FIN should still be sent by TCP?

I hope someone could shed some light on it!

Comment: Did the original application continue to run? Because if the application exits it will implicitly close all still open file descriptors (including sockets) anyway. If instead the application continues to run with the open socket then another application should not be bound to the still allocated port.

Comment: Hi Steffen Ullrich, first of all, thanks for your help! I'm not sure if the application1 was still running at that time, but I would assume the application1 didn't exist when another application2 was up. So if I understand you correctly, you're saying that if the application1 got killed at that time, it's possible the socket will be closed (CLOSE_WAIT state will be gone) and the client won't send FIN to the server, so the socket on the server side would be in FIN_WAIT2 until timeout?

Comment: No, it should do a normal close on application exit, thus sending the FIN. But, if there are still unread data on close it will send a RST instead. This is also true if SO_LINGER was set on the socket - see https://ndeepak.com/posts/2016-10-21-tcprst/ . In this case the socket will probably no longer hang around in some state but the peer socket neither - unless it did not receive the RST. It might be better to ask the question at [networkengineering.se], since this is more on-topic there and you might find better experts in such issues.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for your help and pointing out the direction!  I will try asking this in Network Engineering.